# Error 1025 err 150 in MySql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to drop a foreign key column in a table I have named ProductInvoice. The column I'm trying to drop is named PersonID and is from the table Person. When I run the query

```
ALTER TABLE ProductInvoice
DROP COLUMN PersonID;
```

I get this error...

```
Error Code: 1025. Error on rename of './jkripal/#sql-91c_19ff0' to './jkripal/ProductInvoice' (errno: 150)
```

Any advice on how to trouble shoot this? I've looked around this site and can't find any answers that help.

I also tried these queries

```
ALTER TABLE ProductInvoice DROP FOREIGN KEY `fkPerson`;
ALTER TABLE ProductInvoice DROP COLUMN PersonID;
```

And receive this response...

```
Error Code: 1025. Error on rename of './jkripal/ProductInvoice' to './jkripal/#sql2-91c-1a05a' (errno: 152)
```

These are the results from SHOW CREATE TABLE ProductInvoice

```
'ProductInvoice', 'CREATE TABLE `ProductInvoice` 
(\n  `ProductInvoiceID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
\n  `PersonID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `ProductID` int(11) NOT NULL,
\n  `InvoiceID` int(11) NOT NULL,
\n  `TravelDate` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `TicketNote` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `Quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `InsuranceTicketCode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
\n  PRIMARY KEY (`ProductInvoiceID`),
\n  KEY `fkPerson` (`PersonID`),
\n  KEY `fk_ProductInvoice_to_Product` (`ProductID`),
\n  KEY `fk_ProductInvoice_to_Invoice` (`InvoiceID`),
\n  CONSTRAINT `ProductInvoice_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PersonID`) REFERENCES `Person` (`PersonID`),
\n  CONSTRAINT `ProductInvoice_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ProductID`) REFERENCES `Product` (`ProductID`),
\n  CONSTRAINT `ProductInvoice_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`InvoiceID`) REFERENCES `Invoice` (`InvoiceID`)
\n) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

I have also tried this to no avail

```
ALTER TABLE ProductInvoice DROP FOREIGN KEY `fkPerson`;

DROP INDEX `fkPerson` ON ProductInvoice;
ALTER TABLE ProductInvoice DROP COLUMN PersonID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to drop the foreign key constraint that references the column. To do that, you have to specify the foreign key to be dropped by the *name* of the  CONSTRAINT. Based on the output of shown from show create table, it looks like the constraint is named `ProductInvoice_ibfk_1`.

So, first drop the foreign key constraint:

```
 ALTER TABLE `ProductInvoice` DROP FOREIGN KEY `ProductInvoice_ibfk_1`;
```

Then you can drop the column. (It may also be necessary to drop indexes that reference the column, before you can drop the column.)